# Which fields get persisted to database if I extend from FOSUserBundle User entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am extending my UserBundle from FOSUserbundle. I see the there is a full user class in 
`Model/User.php` and in `Entity/User.php`

I am extending my class as

```
namespace MYS\CoreBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**

 * @ORM\Entity

 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")

 */

class User extends BaseUser

{

     /**

 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255")

 *

 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})

 * @Assert\MinLength(limit="3", message="The name is too short.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})

 * @Assert\MaxLength(limit="255", message="The name is too long.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})

 */

protected $firstName;
```

My Questions are:

1. Are there any database tables generated for FOSUSerbundle User Entity or they are just classes and are not persisted
2. In my above code will my usertable will have only firstname as attribute or all other attributes which are in `Model/User.php` in FosUserBundle
3. Where is the logic where FOSUserBundle is persisting his tables

Answer (score 0):

1. No. You must just update database schema and field $firstName will be a another column in fos_user.
2. See 1.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Yes, a table will be created. But keep in mind that since you're extending the user entity provided by FOSUserBundle with your own, the actual table structure may include additional fields that the FOSUserBundle entity does not have.

2 - Your user table will contain all the fields defined both in FOSUserBundle's user entity, as well as any fields defined in your subclass.

3 - I'm not sure off hand, but have a look through the source code and you will find your answer.